# Facebook share not using updated OG meta

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meta, facebook-sharer, facebook-share

I'm sharing posts on facebook and it's not using my updated OG and meta tags. How long does it take for the changes to make affect.

Comment: Why am I getting a negative vote for this? It's a pretty good question.

Comment: your question is not really as detailed as it should be on stackoverflow, i guess that is why. you should include as much information as possible: a testlink with og tags, what you found out on your own, ...

Comment: FYI, first part of the `title` tooltip on the downvote icon is _“This question does not show any research effort”_ … as if you were the first person ever to have this kind of question …

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the OG tags in the Facebook debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

You can also take a look at this thread with the same question: [Share Cache Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104908/share-cache-timeout)

Answer from the [Like Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) docs:

> **Why and when does Facebook scrape my page?**
>
> Facebook needs to scrape your page to know how to display it around
>   the site. This happens every 24 hours to ensure the properties are up
>   to date. The page is also scraped when the URL is entered into the
>   Debugger Tool.

Btw, there is a nice way to update many pages at once in this thread: [Facebook Open Graph not clearing cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776567/facebook-open-graph-not-clearing-cache/21468084#21468084)